# why say empty function 'resize'?

Tags: python, image-processing, google-colaboratory

the error that i get is .

> error: OpenCV(4.1.2) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/resize.cpp:3720: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'resize'

```
fname_images = np.array(df_skin['image_id'])
file_to_read =('/content/drive/MyDrive/DATASET/HAM10000_images_part_1')+str(fname_images[0])+'.jpg'

import cv2
from cv2 import imread
from cv2 import resize

img = imread(file_to_read)
img2 = resize(img,(100,100))

# show one exampe image

plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.imshow(img[:,:,::-1])
plt.title('Original image')
plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.imshow(img2[:,:,::-1])
plt.title('Resized image for DenseNet')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

`imread()` won't throw an exception if it can't find the image file -- it just returns `None`.  The error occurs when you try to pass this to `resize()`.

I think the pathname to the image file is wrong -- is `HAM10000_images_part_1` a directory? If so, you forgot to add a slash after, and so the code tries to read an image named something like `HAM10000_images_part_1bicycle.jpg` which of course does not exist.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66738031/10794205 see that

Comment: is  a path of groub an images

Comment: @AhmedTamam You need to use the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66737896/edit) link under your question to add more information/details.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Pillow and doing the `.resize((x, y))` on it. And also check the path to make sure everything is good.

Comment: Of course if using Pillow is OK in your case

Comment: what you mean by pillow??

Comment: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ Python Library for handling images. You can use Image.open("path") and afterwards just resize it, also you can turn into a numpy array later when needed. And so much more of course